# Links in Inbox and Achievements panels lead back to insecure, non-https pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, global-inbox, ssl, achievements-dialog

When I'm on, for example, the secure SO site, and then open the "StackExchange" drop-down, links to other SE sites include their "https" equivalent as well, which is expected. *(If I'm on the the regular http site, then the links are all http.)*

[image]

But links to questions via the "Inbox" and "Achievements" drop-downs lead back to the insecure, http equivalent, even when I'm on a secure page.

[image]

[image]

Can those links be generated in such a way that we're kept on the secure version of the site?

Comment: We don't support HTTPS yet.  This is not a bug.  We never link you *to* anything https:// outside the login page, anywhere.

Comment: They are not `https://` ...look at the source, they are simply `//` which means "whatever the page is using" (google protocol or scheme-relative URLs for details).  We're getting things ready, but there are still many, many things to deploy to get there. It's not simple with user-submitted content, a lot more pre-reqs have come up since that  original blog post.

Comment: @NickCraver How's this coming along?  It's been nearly two years - I just noticed the same thing happening - and having just checked the source, it seems that they _are_ now coded to use just `http://` rather than `//` (at least the inbox notifications are, the links to other sites are still `//`).

Comment: @James 6-8 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I asked this, the answer was that https wasn't supported yet.

[Stack Overflow has finally done it!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/22/stack-overflow-flipped-switch-https) *(thank you)*

> As of today, Stack Overflow now deploys HTTPS by default on StackOverflow.com — as well as the hundreds of Q&A communities that make up our Stack Exchange network. We now redirect all traffic to https://, and Google links will change over the next few weeks.

Full (really, *really* full) details from Nick Craver:

[HTTPS on Stack Overflow: The End of a Long Road](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow)